# How can i use a full stop as one of multiple delimiters in python

Tags: python, delimiter

I am trying to figure out how I can user the full stop (.) as a delimiter in a string sentence I am converting into a list. The following is my code

```
    def convert_to_word_list(text):
        word_list = re.split(' |\\, |\\; |\\? |\\.', text)
        print(word_list)
        to_lower_case_list = [word.lower() for word in word_list]
        return to_lower_case_list

print(convert_to_word_list("Hello. my; name, is? Mad Max"))
```

Now if you were to run this code it would return a list of all the strings excluding the
special characters all in lower case, but wherever I add a full stop it prints and empty string instead. For instance the print statement here prints the following:

['hello', '', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'mad', 'max']

With an empty string between hello and my, where the full stop was at the end of hello and this pretty much happens anywhere where i add a full stop

Thank you in advance

Comment: If one of the provided answers solved your question then please consider accepting it. If they didn't then feel free to update your post to explain what problems are still present.

Answer (score 2):

Your other regex fragments are followed by space e.g. `\\,` . You could change `|\\.` to `|\\.`  however none of this will work if there are no spaces. For example `"Hello.Fred"` will result in `['Hello.Fred']`, but you presumably want the result to be `['Hello', 'Fred']`.

Your existing code will also fail with leading whitespace, trailing whitespace, and trailing word separators.

You can try the following:

```
import re

def convert_to_word_list(text):
    word_list = re.split("\\s+|\\,\\s*|\\;\\s*|\\?\\s*|\\.\\s*", text.strip())
    to_lower_case_list = [word.lower() for word in word_list]
    return list(filter(None, to_lower_case_list))

print(convert_to_word_list("Hello.my; name, is? Mad Max")
# result: ['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'mad', 'max']

print(convert_to_word_list("  Hello.Fred.")
# result: ['hello', 'fred']
```

But a better option might be to simply replace non-words with whitespace, then split on whitespace, for example:

```
def convert_to_word_list(s):
    return [w.lower() for w in re.sub(r"[^\w\s]", " ", s).split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting on the delimiters plus any additional spaces:

```
re.split('\,\s*|\;\s*|\?\s*|\.\s*', text)
```

This makes;

```
import re
def convert_to_word_list(text):
        word_list = re.split('\,\s*|\;\s*|\?\s*|\.\s*', text)
        print(word_list)
        to_lower_case_list = [word.lower() for word in word_list]
        return to_lower_case_list

print(convert_to_word_list("Hello. my; name, is? Mad Max"))
```

Output:

```
['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Mad Max']
['hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'mad max']
```